# data- attribute not working to grab dynamic id from foreach

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-pages

I am using JS in a razor page to grab a dynamic ID from a col in a foreach.

In the past, I have used this and it worked fine. However, it seems that it is currently only grabbing the ID from the first col no matter which one I click.

Can someone please tell me if I am still doing this right? Or if I am missing something. Thank you.

View:

```
            <div class="list-group container" id="JobRequestMonitorTable">
            <div class="row list-group-item list-group-item-heading container divTableHeading" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
                <div class="col-md-4"> Job Code </div>
                <div class="col-md-4"> Description </div>
                <div class="col-md-2"> Schedule </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"> Running </div>
                <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            </div>
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorMessage))
            {
                <div class="row list-group-item-danger">
                    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</div>
                </div>
            }
            @foreach (var item in Model.JobRequests)
            {
                <div class="row list-group-item container">
                    <div class="hidden" data-id="@item.JobRequestId" id="requestId">@item.JobRequestId</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">@item.JobCode</div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">@item.Description</div>
                    <div class="col-md-2">@item.Schedule</div>
                    @if (@item.IsRunning == true)
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-left:25px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn"></button>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

JS:

```
        $("button").click(function () {

            var col = $('#requestId');
            var jobRequestId = col.data('Id');

             $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("JobPollerParameters", "Tools")',
                 data: { "jobRequestId": jobRequestId},
                 success: function (results) {

                    $modal = $('#paramsModal');
                    $modal.modal("show");               

                     var arr = results;
                     //loop through arr created from dictionary to grab key(s)
                     for (var key in arr) {
                         if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                             var myKey = key;
                         }
                     }

                     var name = myKey;
                     var value = results[myKey];

                    $('#modalName').text(name);
                     $('#modalMessage').text(value);

                }
            });
        });
```

Really the only important part to see in the JS is `var col = $('#requestId');
            var jobRequestId = col.data('Id');`

But I suppose I will include the whole script just in case people ask.

Comment: Your loop is creating multiple `#requestId` elements when `id` attributes *have to be unique within the DOM*. Change the logic to use classes instead. Then you can traverse the DOM to find the elements related to the button which was clicked

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so just give that col a unique class and use that in the selector?

Comment: Can you use col.attr(‘id’);

Comment: @Jacked_Nerd no use the same class for all of them. I've added an answer to give you a working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is creating multiple `#requestId` and `#paramModalBtn` elements when `id` attributes *have to be unique within the DOM*. Change the logic to use common classes instead. Then you can traverse the DOM to find the elements related to the button which was clicked. Try this:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  var $col = $(this).closest('.row').find('.requestId');
  var jobRequestId = $col.data('id');
  console.log(jobRequestId);
  
  // AJAX request...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="row list-group-item container">
  <div class="hidden requestId" data-id="foo-bar">Job #1</div>
  <!-- other content... -->
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" name="paramsBtn"></button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row list-group-item container">
  <div class="hidden requestId" data-id="lorem-ipsum">#Job #2</div>
  <!-- other content... -->
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" name="paramsBtn"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of your items inside the loop are getting the same `id` attribute, it is hard-codded

```
id="requestId"
```

the jQuery selector `$('#requestId')` is getting back the first one, this is by design.

I would add a `data-id` to each button and select the relevant col with that id.

For example the button will get:

```
<button data-col-id="@item.JobRequestId" class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary"></button>
```

And then, its easy to grab that info on click:

```
$("button").click(function () {

            var jobRequestId = $(this).data('col-id');

             $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("JobPollerParameters", "Tools")',
                 data: { "jobRequestId": jobRequestId},
                 success: function (results) {

                    $modal = $('#paramsModal');
                    $modal.modal("show");               

                     var arr = results;
                     //loop through arr created from dictionary to grab key(s)
                     for (var key in arr) {
                         if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                             var myKey = key;
                         }
                     }

                     var name = myKey;
                     var value = results[myKey];

                    $('#modalName').text(name);
                     $('#modalMessage').text(value);

                }
            });
        });
```

I like this solution as you are not depended on your HTML structure and hierarchy thus selectors won't break often.

Comment: This approach is similar to the one I've posted. If it works, you should mark it as accepted (and ignore mine's). :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a button for each item, you could also store the data into the button value attribute, which leads to a simple implementation in the JS:

```js
$("button").click(function (e) {

    var jobRequestId = $(e.target).val();
    console.log(jobRequestId);

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("JobPollerParameters", "Tools")',
         data: { "jobRequestId": jobRequestId},
         success: function (results) {

            $modal = $('#paramsModal');
            $modal.modal("show");               

             var arr = results;
             //loop through arr created from dictionary to grab key(s)
             for (var key in arr) {
                 if (arr.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                     var myKey = key;
                 }
             }

             var name = myKey;
             var value = results[myKey];

            $('#modalName').text(name);
             $('#modalMessage').text(value);

        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn" value="1">Job 1</button><br />
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn" value="2">Job 2</button><br />
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn" value="3">Job 3</button><br />
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn" value="4">Job 4</button><br />
<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn" value="5">Job 5</button>
```

Obs.: value must be equal to `@item.JobRequestId` like so: `<button class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt btn btn-primary" id="paramModalBtn" name="paramsBtn" value="@item.JobRequestId">Job 5</button>`